# Evaluate $\int_{-2}^{0}\sqrt{10-4x}\;dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The problem below looks like this but I'm not sure where to go from here:
$$\int_{-2}^{0}\sqrt{10-4x}\,dx $$

$$u=10-4x
\qquad du=4\,dx$$

$$\int_{10}^{18}{\sqrt{u}\over 4}\;$$

Is this heading the write direction, any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, some notes:

- The substitution $u=10-4x$ is in fact the right call.
- This will change the bounds. Lower bound goes from $-2$ to $u(-2) = 18$, and the upper bound goes from $0$ to $u(0) = 10$.
- Your $\mathrm{d}u$ should have a negative factor. Essentially, find $\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}x$ and multiply both sides by $\mathrm{d}x$. Then you get that $\mathrm{d}u = -4 \, \mathrm{d}x$ and so $\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}u/(-4)$.

With all of these in mind, then

$$\int_{-2}^0 \sqrt{10-4x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{18}^{10} \sqrt{u} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{-4}$$

You can then bring the $-1/4$ out, and multiply the integral by $-1$ to put the bounds in the correct order, so

$$\int_{18}^{10} \sqrt{u} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{-4}
= -\frac 1 4 \int_{18}^{10} \sqrt{u} \, \mathrm{d}u
= \frac 1 4 \int_{10}^{18} \sqrt{u} \, \mathrm{d}u$$

So ultimately the same integral as what you got, but you gotta be careful about those details. I suspect you just had the $10$ and $18$ in the right order straightaway, and forgot about the $-1$ from the differential, two mistakes which cancelled out. The new lower bound always replaces the old lower bound, even if it means the new lower bound is bigger. Same with the upper bound.

---

But in general, you've got the right spirit. What remains is just to find the integral. You can find this with the power rule. Recall that

$$\int u^n \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$$

and that $\sqrt u = u^{1/2}$ to apply this to your current integral (alongside the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, of course).

Comment: Would the answer be 1/6 (18^3/2 - 10^3/2) @PrincessEev

Comment: Yes $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$